# mysql - Using ABS() and applying label with "AS"

Tags: mysql

My current sql statement is

```
"SELECT ID,ABS(tvshows-$tvshows) + ABS(actionandadventure-$actionandadventure) + ABS(anime-$anime) + ABS(childrenandfamily-$childrenandfamily) + ABS(classics-$classics) + ABS(comidies-$comidies) + ABS(cultmovies-$cultmovies) + ABS(documentaries-$documentaries) + ABS(dramas-$dramas) + ABS(faith-$faith) + ABS(foreign1-$foreign1) + ABS(gay-$gay) + ABS(horror-$horror) + ABS(independent-$independent) + ABS(music-$music) + ABS(musicals-$musicals) + ABS(independent-$independent) + ABS(music-$music) + ABS(musicals-$musicals) + ABS(romance-$romance) + ABS(scifi-$scifi) + ABS(sports-$sports) + ABS(thrillers-$thrillers) as total FROM accounts WHERE ID != '$ID' ORDER BY total ASC LIMIT 20
```

What I would like to do is have an individual label to each ABS such as

```
"SELECT ID,ABS(tvshows-$tvshows) AS totaltvshows + ABS(actionandadventure-$actionandadventure) AS totalactionandadventure + etc...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What would the label do? Do you mean you want a column for each item as well as the total?

Comment: can't you just do something like "SELECT ID,ABS(tvshows-$tvshows) AS totaltvshows, ..., totaltvshows + ... FROM ?

Answer (score 2):

Impossible. You cannot alias the sub-components of an expression. e.g. you're trying to do the equivalent of:

SELECT 1 AS one + 2 AS two

and somehow expecting mysql to turn that into two separate fields/columns. No, it won't do that. You're doing addition. You'll get back **ONE** column with the result of your addition, and you can alias that result.

```
SELECT (1 + 2) AS result
```

would work

If you want the individual components, then write them out:

```
SELECT ABS(a+b) AS part1, ABS(c+d) AS part2, ABS(a+b) + ABS(c+d) AS result
```